# AWS Amplify: While retaining AppSync, Is it possible to use Aurora instead of DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I want to create an AWS Amplify application using the following services:

- amplify add auth: **AWS Cognito**
- amplify add api: **GraphQL (AWS AppSync)**

But I don't want to use DynamoDB but **Amazon Aurora**.
How can I do that?

I don't want use REST API but **GraphQL** with **AWS AppSync**.
Why?

Answers: Because with Appsync I can use the **Subscription** and I would like to use Queries like that:

```
type Post @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner }]) {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
}
```

(It's very easy the manage the permission and allow request for logged user only).

Is it possible? If yes, how can I do that?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

It's fully documented here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-rds-resolvers.html

You must ensure you enable the data API for your Aurora Serverless. Also be aware of the cost implications when moving from DynamoDB to Aurora.

Comment: Hello @lee-hannigan and thank you for your answer. I already know how use with AppSync. My question is "How can I do this with Amplify?" Do you use amplify? (If the answer is no, you cannot understand my problem).